# Implementing dynamic multiselect with typeahead feature in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am writing a Google Apps Script for Gmail. The app has a form that allows for creation of an entity. The form includes a multi-select field, which needs to work as a typeahead.

I've looked at the `AutoComplete` and `SuggestionList` and although it does not allow for `id, label`, I can work with just passing text as value and then do a look up when I receive the POST. However, this does not allow for `multiSelect`. Again a work-around for this is to create an array and store it in `userProperty` and use the value of that during POST.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/suggestions-response?hl=en

However, this then does not allow for a user to remove a selected value. I thought, I can use a list of `imageButton` to list all selected items, but unfortunately, Google Apps Script does not allow updating a card once it's built.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/image-button?hl=en

Ideally, I am looking to implement `Material Chips` style UI - https://material.io/components/chips

Comment: Hey there! Would you mind providing more details about the question you are addressing? Would you like to achieve a functionality similar to the one Material Chips has?

Comment: Hi, yes that would be ideal but I know the limitations of Apps Script. I basically want to allow a user to select multiple values from a result set based on a text search. AutoComplete allows me to achieve searching but not selecting multiple values. Also, apps script does not allow for hidden Fields.